# grep redirect non-matching

Tags: bash, file, command-line, grep

I'm doing a simple **grep** for lines starting with some patteren like:

```
grep -E "^AAA" myfile > newfile
```

I would like to also (in the same go) redirect those non-matching lines to another file.
I know it would be possible to simply do it twice and use **-v** in the second try, but the files are (relatively) huge and only reading them once would save some quite valuable time...

I was thinking something along the line of redirecting non-matching to stderr like:

```
grep -E -magic_switch "^AAA" myfile > newfile 2> newfile.nonmatch
```

Is this trick somehow possible with **grep** or should I rather just code it?

(might be of additional value - I'm coding this in bash script)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This will work:

```
awk '/pattern/ {print; next} {print > "/dev/stderr"}' inputfile
```

or

```
awk -v matchfile=/path/to/file1 -v nomatchfile=/path/to/file2 '/pattern/ {print > matchfile; next} {print > nomatchfile}' inputfile
```

or

```
#!/usr/bin/awk -f
BEGIN {
    pattern     = ARGV[1]
    matchfile   = ARGV[2]
    nomatchfile = ARGV[3]
    for (i=1; i<=3; i++) delete ARGV[i]
}

$0 ~ pattern {
    print > matchfile
    next
}

{
    print > nomatchfile
}
```

Call the last one like this:

```
./script.awk regex outputfile1 outputfile2 inputfile
```

Comment: Nice! I always prefer using standard tools to writing code and one-liners are worth extra points ;)

Answer (score 2):

I fear this may not be possible. I'd use Perl and do something like:

```
if (/^AAA/) {
   print STDOUT $_;
}
else
{
   print STDERR $_;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe this can be done with `grep`, but it's only a few lines of Perl:

```
#! /usr/bin/perl
# usage: script regexp match_file nomatch_file < input

my $regexp = shift;
open(MATCH, ">".shift);
open(NOMATCH, ">".shift);

while(<STDIN>) {
    if (/$regexp/o) {
        print MATCH $_;
    } else {
        print NOMATCH $_;
    }
}
```

or Python, if you prefer:

```
#! /usr/bin/python
# usage: script regexp match_file nomatch_file < input

import sys
import re

exp = re.compile(sys.argv[1])
match = open(sys.argv[2], "w")
nomatch = open(sys.argv[3], "w")

for line in sys.stdin:
    if exp.match(line): match.write(line)
    else:               nomatch.write(line)
```

(Both totally untested.  Your mileage may vary.  Void where prohibited.)

Comment: happythankyouverymuch! I'll just take the py code ... you just saved me 5 minutes of browsing thru reference ;)

Answer (score 2):

You can use process substitution to duplicate the pipe as the file is being read (inspiration https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/71511).  This should be almost as performant, since the file is still only being read once.

Something like this should work:

`cat file.txt | tee >(grep 'pattern' > matches.txt) | grep -v 'pattern' > non-matches.txt`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a function for you:

```
function perg {
  awk '{y = $0~z ? "out" : "err"; print > "/dev/std" y}' z="$1" "$2"
}
```

Use it with a file

```
perg ^AAA myfile > newfile 2> newfile.nonmatch
```

or from a pipe

```
cat myfile | perg ^AAA > newfile 2> newfile.nonmatch
```